# Leadbolt banner dont show

Tags: android, leadbolt

I must implement leadbolt banner in Android APP. I use the latest LeadBolt App SDK (6.0).
From the their pdf instruction i do:
in  OnCreate:

```
     lb = new AdController(this,"MY ID",bannerListener);
     lb.loadAd();


 private AdListener bannerListener = new AdListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onAdResumed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Logger.i("IAdv_LeadBolt_BannerMC", "onAdResumed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdProgress() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Logger.i("IAdv_LeadBolt_BannerMC", "onAdProgress");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdPaused() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Logger.i("IAdv_LeadBolt_BannerMC", "onAdPaused");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Logger.i("IAdv_LeadBolt_BannerMC", "onAdLoaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Logger.i("IAdv_LeadBolt_BannerMC", "onAdFailed  "+lb.adShowStatus());
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdCompleted() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Logger.i("IAdv_LeadBolt_BannerMC", "onAdCompleted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Logger.i("IAdv_LeadBolt_BannerMC", "onAdClosed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Logger.i("IAdv_LeadBolt_BannerMC", "onAdClicked");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdAlreadyCompleted() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Logger.i("IAdv_LeadBolt_BannerMC", "onAdAlreadyCompleted");
        }
    };
```

and also I write

```
       controller.setLayout((RelativeLayout) viewGroup);
```

to show it.

But always I see the log from OnAdFailed method

```
          @Override
        public void onAdFailed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Logger.i("IAdv_LeadBolt_BannerMC", "onAdFailed  "+lb.adShowStatus());
        }
```

Anybody know what I am doing wrong&